# Resources: decriminalization timeline list

Tags: reference-request, research

I'm curious as to what decriminalization laws have been passed through out the years and at what times around the world.

Are there any sort of lists or resources that deal with decriminalization laws in this way?

For instance:

- 2015 Korea decriminalized the crime of adultery
- 2015 America (lots of states) decriminalized marijuana

Comment: Some relevant links may be found here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decriminalization